# SFTP sending files between laptops on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ftp, sftp, vsftpd

I want to transfer files between two Ubuntu systems using SFTP. I have got it set-up and I can connect to the other laptop, ping it and see its file list using `sftp> dir`. I can see the files on the other system.

But when I call `get filename.deb` it comes up saying

```
Fetching /home/user/filename.deb to filename.deb 0% 0 0.0KB/s --:-- ETA
```

and then drops back to the sftp> command promote without transferring anything. Have I missed something?

Comment: When you increase logging using `-v` option on the initial `sftp` command, what is reported? (hint: cut&paste)

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is a specific reason why you need sftp, ssh is much easier. It is also secure and encrypted. To install the ssh service run this command on both computers:

```
$sudo apt-get install ssh
```

You can then use secure copy to transfer the files:

```
user@local_machine $ scp user@remote_machine:home/user/filename.deb .
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this trick on the Ubuntu forums: have you tried changing the mtu on your interface?

```
sudo ifconfig <interface> mtu 1490
```

Where interface is probably `eth0` or `wlan0`.

Comment: If that does will do the trick, there's some basic network error and more applications will suffer from it. One should not have to change the MTU on his local inteface in order to make such stuff work. So basically, you're then just killing symptoms rather fixing actual problems.